# $A^3 = I$ and $A ≠ I$, show A not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I was able to show that $A^3 - I = 0$ then $(A-I)(A^2+A+I) = 0 $ then $A^2+A+I =0$, but as to show why it means A is (or isn't) diagonalizable over $R$, I'm stuck.

any help in directions for the proof will be appreciated!

Comment: @HereToRelax I forgot to add its over the Real numbers

Comment: If you know about minimal polynomials and their relationship to diagonalisability, then you can simply observe $x^3 - 1$ is a square-free polynomial.

Comment: If it is over $\mathbb{R}$, then it is not diagonalizable; the minimal polynomial would have to divide $A-I$, and that would require $A=I$, which is explicitly excluded. That means the minimal polynomial, over $\mathbb{R}$, must be divisible by $t^2+t+1$, which does not split over $\mathbb{R}$, so the matrtix is not diagonalizable. Over $\mathbb{C}$, it is because $t^3-1$ splits and has no repeated factors, hence the same is true for the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Troposphere to show diagonalizability no, but the second part says to show the minimal polynomial is $x^3 - 1$ for odd dimensions

Comment: Why $(A-I)(A^2+A+I)=0$ implies $A^2+A+I=0$? The ring of matrices is not an integral domain. Anyway, the statement you want to prove is not true.

Comment: @Mark I might be wrong about that assumption. I realized the statement is probably not true, Im just not sure how to prove it isnt

Comment: If a matrix is diagonalizable over a field $F$ then its minimal polynomial splits over $F$. So if your matrix was diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ then all the complex roots of its minimal polynomial would belong to $\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand, the roots of the minimal polynomial must be roots of $x^3-1$. So we conclude that if $A$ is diagonalizable then $1$ is its only eigenvalue. (it is the only root of $x^3-1$ which belongs to $\mathbb{R}$). From here we get that its minimal polynomial must be $x-1$, but then $A=I$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a proof that if $A$ is a matrix with real entries satisfying $A^3 = I$ with $A \neq I$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$.

First, we note that $A^2 + A + I$ is not invertible. Indeed, suppose that this matrix is invertible. It would follow that
$$
A^3 - I = 0 \implies (A^2 +A + I)(A - I) = 0 \implies A - I = 0 \implies A = I,
$$
contradicting our assumption that $A \neq I$.

Now, let $\omega_1,\omega_2$ denote the two (non-real) complex roots of $\omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$. We have
$$
\det(A^2 + A + I) = 0 \implies \det((A - \omega_1 I)(A - \omega_2 I)) = 0 \\
\implies \det(A - \omega_1 I)\det(A - \omega_2 I) = 0.
$$
Thus, it must holds that $\det(A - \omega_1 I) = 0$ or $\det(A - \omega_2 I) = 0$. Thus, $A$ has an eigenvalue that is not real. Thus, $A$ cannot be diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: why does the first part equates to A = I ?

Comment: @Aaron There are 3 steps in going from $A^3 - I = 0$ to $A = I$. Which step do you have trouble with?

Comment: from second to third, since if $AB = 0$ that doesnt mean one of each must be $0$, right?

Comment: @Aaron If $A$ is invertible and $AB = 0$, then 
$$
AB = 0 \implies A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}0 \implies B = 0.
$$

Comment: I understand, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample take the matrix describing a rotation of $120°$. For dimension higher than two fill the rest of the matrix with $1$'s in the diagonal and zero elsewhere.